# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes on loading installation from bootable USB

Tags: ubuntu, asus-laptop

My laptop:

> ASUS N552
>
> Cpu : Intel Core i7 6700
>
> Gpu : Nvidia GTX960m dual with Intel HD graphics

It's working fine with Windows 10 but when I try to dual boot it with Ubuntu it freezes at ubuntu loading page.

I disabled fast startup in Windows 10.

I also tried with Kali linux, and I have the same freezing problem when I want to login to desktop!

What should I do ? 
How can I disable nvidia graphics ?

**Update**:
Finally managed to install it by adding nomodeset after kernel boot flags in grub...

But in login page after I input my password and press enter , screen freezes and nothing happens.

Comment: I have the same problem (it freezes seconds after login) and the same CPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fortunately, i solved it finally :)

the problem was with nouveau Graphics Drivers, so i disabled it in the booting process by adding code below to the end of linux kernel flags in grub :

```
nouveau.modeset=0
```

Answer (score 0):

For those whose Ubuntu 16.04 installation is still froze after adding `nomodeset` to the kernel boot flags in grub. Please try adding `noapic` and `nolapic` to the kernel boot flags as well. It worked for me on a fairly old Pentium Dual-Core 32-bit machine.